Why is audio and WiFi not working after Windows 10 update?
I'm facing an issue where my audio device is not working after installing Windows 10 and Realtek drivers. I initially installed Windows 10 on my system.
After the installation, I found that my audio device was recognized, but there was no sound output.
To resolve this, I installed the Realtek audio driver.
However, after the installation, my audio device is now showing as "Not Found."
I followed several troubleshooting steps I found online and then restarted my PC, but the issue still exist.
I would like to know the correct way to fix my audio device on my PC.

"the Realtek audio driver" - which one, specifically. Realtek make more than one audio device. Which one does your system have, specifically

Sorry but I will have to renew the question again
